# Using string in place of property name (LINQ)

Tags: string, linq

I have been able to get the values from tables using linq.

```
var q=(from app in context.Applicant 
        where app.ApplicantName=="")
```

Now what I want is this:

```
 var q=(from app in context.Applicant 
        where app.stringIhave =="")  // so instead of column name I have string which has same name as column.
```

**Is it possible to specify string in Select as this is not sure what I will get in each case, I need different data all the time.**

Is it possible to do so?
If no, then I will figure out something else.
**Update**
I have a GlobalString, which holds the column name of a table.
So when I query that table, I only specify from string which column value I want to get:

```
var q=(from app in context.Applicants
       where app.ID==1013
       select GlobalString //which is specifying that I want to get value from which column, as column name is not fixed.
 //where GlobalString can have values like: app.FirstName..app.LastName etc
```

**Update1:**

```
var q = context.Applicants.Select("new(it.ApplicantFirstName as FirstName, it.ApplicantLastName as LastName)");
```

Error Message:

```
The query syntax is not valid. Near keyword 'AS'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) (available from NuGet) for that:

```
   var q = context.Applicant.Where(app.stringIhave + " = @0", "");
```

Comment: i think you need add that `app` in your sample is not same that `app` in OP

Comment: @ItiTyagi yep, you can pass string to `Select` too

Comment: @ItiTyagi can you provide code what you try do, and what you whant get?

Comment: @ItiTyagi code above works just fine. Maybe you have specified wrong property name or value to filter. For your edit code will look like `context.Applicants.Where("ID=@0", 1013).Select("PropertyName")`

Answer (score 0):

for select you can try something like this

```
var q = context.Applicant.Select("new(it.FirstName as FirstName, it.LastName as LastName)");
```

so you only need construct string for that format

Comment: @ItiTyagi, do you can provide error message, and sample code what you tried? Also it sample work for `Dynamic Linq` only

Comment: @ItiTyagi it strange, but try without as

Comment: I tried my best, by shuffling syntax, but like this its not working.

Comment: on new test project its work, possibly you can provide little more code or input data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43597/discussion-between-iti-tyagi-and-grundy)

Comment: try select one column like `var q = context.Applicants.Select("ApplicantFirstName")` its work?